# Ninject IOC bindings and StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

So I currently have a straightforward service like so:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public ServiceA()
    {
    }
}
```

And it's binded like so and works as expected.

```
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces" to="Services.ServiceA, Services" scope="Singleton"/>
```

I'm trying to introduce another service which is like a routing service (support legacy stuff by executing ServiceA's functionality or some new functionality (ServiceB) based on some criteria). It also inherits the same interface as the above service like so:

```
public class RoutingService : IRoutingService, IServiceA
{
    private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
    private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;

    public RoutingService(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this._serviceA = serviceA;
        this._serviceB = serviceB;
    }
    
    public void MethodA(string code)
    {
        if (code.StartsWith('Z'))
        {
            this._serviceA.DoWork();
        }
        else
        {
            this._serviceB.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

I want an app to use either the implementation of ServiceA or RoutingService. How can I achieve this?

I've tried to create an instance like so by using the following bindings and code below however as RoutingService implements and relies on ServiceA, I get into a StackOverflowException on the following line:

```
service = context.Kernel.Get<IServiceA>("routing");
```

**CODE**

Bindings:

```
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces" toProvider="ServiceProvider, App" />
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces" to="Services.ServiceA, Services" scope="Singleton" name="default" />
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces" to="Services.RoutingService, Services" scope="Singleton" name="routing" />
```

The ServiceProvider contains logic like so:

```
protected override IServiceA CreateInstance(IContext context)
{
    IServiceA service;
    
    bool useRoutingService = true; //TODO

    if (useRoutingService)
    {
        service = context.Kernel.Get<IServiceA>("routing");
    }
    else
    {
        service = context.Kernel.Get<IServiceA>("default");
    }
    
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you are getting a `StackOverflowException`

`ServiceB` **does not** rely on `ServiceA`. `ServiceB` **implements** and **relies on** `IServiceA`.

And because `ServiceB` is being instantiated when an `IServiceA` is being resolved and at the same time `ServiceB` requires an `IServiceA` it will indefinitely try to resolve `ServiceB` over and over, since that's how it tries to resolve the constructor parameter.

Step by step this is what happens:

1. Ninject is told to instantiate a `ServiceB` when a `IServiceA` is requested
2. You request an `IServiceA`
3. Ninject tries to instantiate a `ServiceB` (since that's what it was told in step 1)
4. Ninject sees that `ServiceB` requires an instance of `IServiceA` before it can instantiate the `ServiceB` (because `ServiceB` takes `IServiceA` in the constructor)
5. Ninject tries to instantiate a `ServiceB` (since that's what it was told in step 1) to provide the parameter from step 4.
6. Repeat from step 4 indefinitely

---

### How to solve the circular dependency

First off, I'd suggest you rethink whether this is the right approach to support "legacy stuff". This setup seems a little fishy, but I can't really give advice based on the theoretical example (for the future try to be as specific and concrete in your questions as you can - that way you'll get better help).

To focus on the design at hand: one way you can overcome this issue is to specify that your `RoutingService` specifically depends on the legacy implementation of `IServiceA`. You can do this using named bindings like you're already doing in other places (full disclosure: I haven't used Ninject specifically myself, so I'm relying on the documentation alone):

```cs
public class RoutingService : IRoutingService, IServiceA
{
    public RoutingService(
        [Named("legacy")] IServiceA serviceA,
        IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this._serviceA = serviceA;
        this._serviceB = serviceB;
    }
}
```

And your bindings:

```xml
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces"
      to="Services.ServiceA, Services"
      scope="Singleton"
      name="legacy" />
<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceA, Interfaces"
      to="Services.RoutingService, Services"
      scope="Singleton"
      name="routing" />

<bind service="Interfaces.IServiceB, Interfaces"
      to="Services.WhateverServiceB, Services"
      scope="Singleton" />
```

Do note: since both `ServiceA` and `RoutingService` as using named bindings you always have to specify the name whenever one is needed. You can now resolve/get the service like so (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1UWEtV) for an example):

```
var service = kernel.Get<IServiceA>("routing");
// service is a RoutingService
```

A word of advice though: resolving services like this (aka the "Service locator pattern") is generally bad practice for pure dependency injection. Instead you should inject into the constructor or similar. Perhaps your post was just an example but it's worth noting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So for more details, in the long term, I'm planning to delete ServiceA and ServiceB is like a routing service. ServiceB will call ServiceA's methods, to support legacy stuff, or call other methods, depending on some logic. I could remove ServiceA all together but I want to be able to have the option to switch back to ServiceA if needed.

Comment: @Bhav So you want `ServiceB` to specifically use the implementation in `ServiceA` and not some arbitrary implementation of `IServiceA`? In that case I would either suggest making `ServiceB` extend `ServiceA` or specifically require `ServiceA` in the constructor of `ServiceB` - and then only configure Ninject to resolve `ServiceB` for the `IServiceA` interface. More meaningful names would make this conversation easier xD

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the OP with more details to hopefully explain things in more details. What do you mean by the second option? Can you post an answer please.

Comment: Not using a name/using just the second block of code, I get an error 'Error activating IServiceA. More than one matching bindings are available.' hence why I've been trying to use a name attribute in the bindings.

Comment: @Bhav I corrected the answer - I guess that's where my Ninject knowledge stopped :) I added a fiddle as an example. I couldn't find a way to make it work with both a named and unnamed binding at the same time. Hope this works for you